# Angular5: ngPreserveWhiteSpaces does not work in module

Tags: angular

In components which are directly in my application’s main module, I can use the `ngPreserveWhiteSpaces` attribute with the expected result (i.e.: whitespace is preserved in production builds).
While migrating some code to a new submodule in the very same application, I found that this does *not* work – on the other hand, setting `preserveWhitespaces: true` on the `@Component` decorator *does* work.

In other words, the code …

```
<p ngPreserveWhiteSpaces>
    <a [routerLink]="...">Link 1</a>
    <a [routerLink]="...">Link 2</a>
</p>
```

… in the submodule behaves as if the `ngPreserveWhiteSpaces` was not present, while the very same code works in the main module. But preserving the whitespaces for the whole component (without using the `ngPreserveWhiteSpaces` attribute) works also on the submodule:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './my.component.html',
    preserveWhitespaces: true,
})
```

Any hints on why the attribute is not recognized in the submodule?

Angular version is 5.2.9, and `tsconfig.json` contains:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "preserveWhitespaces": false
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: I added the relevant parts.